# Cannot implicitly convert type object to int error combobox

Tags: c#

I recently converted this code from VB and how can i invoke the combobox `cmb_UserID` properly?

```
string strQuery = "";
try
{
    var val = 1;
    val = cmb_UserID.SelectedValue;

    strQuery = "select *from tbl_category where category_id=" + val.ToString + "";

    cmb_UserID.DataSource = c.loadToComboBox(strQuery);
    cmb_UserID.ValueMember = c.loadToComboBox(strQuery).Columns["category_id"].ToString();
    cmb_UserID.DisplayMember = c.loadToComboBox(strQuery).Columns["category_name"].ToString();

}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Comment: Why do you first declare `val` and then immediately assign it a different value? Why not just `var val = cmb_UserID.SelectedValue;`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], there are simply too many problems with the code at hand to properly address your issue. SQL injection, unknown methods, unknown where the exact error occurs, swallowing exceptions, etc. All of this tells me that it is extremely uncertain that you know where the problem occurs and what problem occurs. After you know these two things we can start to address *why* the problem occurs. Also, you say you converted it from VB, if you're going to *not* post an [mcve], can we please see the original VB code?

Comment: Use `val.ToString()`

Comment: val.ToString should be  val.ToString ()

Comment: wait here is the vb code   Try
            Dim val = 1
            val = cboCategory.SelectedValue

            strQuery = "select *from tbl_category where category_id=" & val.ToString & ""

            cboCategory.DataSource = order.loadToComboBox(strQuery)
            cboCategory.ValueMember = order.loadToComboBox(strQuery).Columns("category_id").ToString
            cboCategory.DisplayMember = order.loadToComboBox(strQuery).Columns("category_name").ToString
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

Comment: @PaulF: That is correct, but that would give a different error, "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'".

Comment: there is not enough information to check what is wrong, I know you know the code and it might seem obvious to you but there are so many questions. 1. Why to reassing val? 2. What is "c"? What does it returns? 3. Why empty catch?

Comment: Also you need to explicitly cast SelectedValue to Int

Comment: Please post all code into the questions. It´s quite hard to read it within the comments.

Comment: Oh my, so what operator is appropriate for the val.tostring?

Comment: cant you assign c.loadToComboBox(strQuery) to another object? Do you have to call it everytime?

Comment: I hate to think what `loadToComboBox` is doing when you're calling it 3 times. If it's building a DataTable from the database query each time, that's very wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `val` is of type `int`, due to `var val = 1` assignment. `SelectedValue` property is of type `object`, that discrepancy between types causes given exception.

In order to circumvent that, you need to explicitly cast `SelectedValue` as an `int`

```
val = (int)cmb_UserID.SelectedValue
```

Update:
If you want to use Int32.TryParse instead:

```
var val = 1;
Int32.TryParse(cmb_UserID.SelectedValue.ToString(), out val);
```

Comment: `Int32.TryParse()` is a better option.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I agree

Comment: Okay, and i will try to apply it

Comment: Is it like this? val = Int32.TryParse();
                val = cmb_UserID.SelectedValue;

Comment: I do apologise, i'm just a newbie in c#